# Producer/Consumer : 1 producer, multiple consumers - 1 semaphore, 1 mutex, 1 conditional variable

Tags: c, producer-consumer

I'm implementing the Producer/Consumer problem in C with some specific criteria:

1. 1 producer, multiple consumers
2. using only one mutex, one semaphore, one conditional variable
3. All consumers have to consume (like a broadcast), and then, when all that producer have produced is already consumed by consumers, producer will produce more.

I don't know how to implement it using only what I should according to criteria above.

Here is the pseudo code I've wrote using 3 mutexes only and I can't do it according to criteria.

Any help will be appreciated, I have no idea how to use here just one mutex, where to put semaphore and conditional variable.

> *Pseudo code:*
>
> **WRITER:**
>
> ```
> glock();  //lock from reader
>
> write_lock(); //wait till there is no readers
>
> //write the data
>
> write_unlock();
>
> g_unlock();
> ```
>
> **READER:**
>
> ```
> g_lock();  //so reader can't read when writer locked g and writting
> g_unlock();
>
> read_lock();
> reader++;
> if (reader == 1)
>     write_lock();   ///all consumers have consume 
>
> //read the data
>
> read_lock();
> reader--;
> if (reader == 0)
>     write_unlock();
> read_lock();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution which uses 1 mutex and two conditional variables which can support multiple producers-consumers. Pseudo code is in c++

First read the thread safe buffer queue implementation [here](https://codeistry.wordpress.com/2018/03/08/buffer-queue-handling-in-multithreaded-environment/).

Then check producer consumer solution https://codeistry.wordpress.com/2018/03/09/unordered-producer-consumer/.